# Change white background of GridControl Devexpress WPF

Tags: wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

Please i need change background color of gridcontrol, i tried "" in the gridcontrol and in the CardView, but though I always try out white.

Comment: <Grid Background="Red"/> sets the background of Grid to red as expected. 
In your case probably the elements inside the Grid are overlapping. like the below code doesn't show any red background of Grid as Button overlaps it
<Grid Background="Red"> 
    <Button>Click</Button> 
</Grid>
.
If this is the case try setting the background of contained elements to Transparent like 
<Grid Background="Red">
    <Button Background="Transparent">Click</Button>
</Grid>

Answer (score 1):

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:dxgt="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid/themekeys">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="{dxgt:TableViewThemeKey IsThemeIndependent=true, ResourceKey=DataPresenterTemplate}" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:DataPresenter}">
            <Border Background="Red">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <dxg:GridControl .../>

</Window>
```

Taken from http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q332901

Comment: Tnk, but no found. The background is still white.